# How to refer to variables in a Kubernetes deployment file?

Tags: kubernetes

Sometimes there are variables in the deployment yaml file which are not pre-specified and will be known only during deployment (For example name and tag for the image of a container).

Normally we put a marker text (e.g. `{{IMAGE_NAME}}`) in the yaml file and use a bash text manipulation tools to change it with actual value in the deployment file.

Is there a way to use environment variables or other methods (like using arguments when running `kubectl create`) instead of text-replace tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've done is use envvars in the deployment configuration, then run `apply`/`create` with the output from an [`envsubst`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) command:

deployment.yaml file:

```
[...]
spec:
  replicas: $REPLICA_COUNT
  revisionHistoryLimit: $HISTORY_LIM
[...]
```

during deploy:

```
$ export REPLICA_COUNT=10 HISTORY_LIM=10
$ envsubst < deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to use environment variables directly with kubectl. The common solution is to use some kind of a templating language + processing as you suggested.